# Is it possible to print a html page with something stuck to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, printing

Is it possible to print a html page with something stuck to the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a CSS stylesheet to be used for a media type of print and include that in your webpage. In that stylesheet set appropriate options to "turn on" the footer element that you want whilst in the "screen" version that element might not be visible.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="style.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 @media print { 
    .footer {display: block;}
 }
 @media screen {
    .footer {display: none;}
 }
```

anything of `class=footer` will appear only in print. It's up to you to locate it at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean right at the bottom, instead of immediately after a short amount of content, then perhaps try

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```

Is that the kind of thing you mean?